# How to access a specific element using python etree based on its index

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml file that looks that way :

```
<record>
 <cf tag='id'>A1eF4GT</cf>
 <df tag='123'>
  <sf tag='a'>Foo</sf>
  <sf> tag='u'>Bar</sf>
 </df>
 <df tag='123'>
 <sf tag='a'>Truc</sf>
 <sf tag='u'>Machin</sf>
</df>
</record>
```

I want to parse it with Python Etree and I'm just trying to get "A1eF4GT;Foo/Bar;Truc/Machin". So far I used findall to iterate over the df tag='123', but I can't manage to get the right pairs, and all I get is "A1eF4GT;Foo/Bar;Truc/Bar", since "Bar" is the first thing my code meets when using 'find'. I guess that there is some kinf of index that would help me to get the position of my df tag='123' and then assign the right value, but I cannot find something useful in the documentation.The portion of my code dealing with this looks like this:

```
for record in datafields:
    id=record.find(".//cf[@tag='id']")
    id=id.text.encode('utf8')
    if record.findall("df[@tag='123']/sf[@code='a']"):
        listequiv=[]
        
        for equiv in record.findall("df[@tag='123']/sf[@code='a']"):
            equiv=equiv.text
            equiv2=record.find("df[@tag='123']/sf[@code='u']")
            equiv2=equiv2.text                
            listequiv.append(equiv+'/'+equiv2)
            
        stringequiv=';'.join(listequiv)
        
       
            
        print ark+';'+stringequiv
```

I hope I'm clear enough (sorry I'm not an IT guy...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your code (provide a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a known tree-like structure, so you have to find `df` records first, and then find `sf` records inside each of those.

For example, list of `df` records

```
>>> record.findall("df")
[<Element 'df' at 0x000001E32A942C20>, <Element 'df' at 0x000001E32A942D10>]
```

Iteration example:

```
>>> for elem in record.findall("df"):
...     for sub_elem in elem.findall("sf"):
...         print(sub_elem.text)
...
HALLO
Bar
Truc
Machin
```

Your example (had to drop encode to `utf-8` to `join` to work

```
>>> listequiv = []
>>> cf_text = record.find(".//cf[@tag='id']").text
>>> listequiv.append(cf_text)
>>>
>>> for elem in record.findall("df"):
...     sf_elems = []
...     for sub_elem in elem.findall("sf"):
...         sf_elems.append(sub_elem.text)
...     listequiv.append("/".join(sf_elems))
...
>>> print(";".join(listequiv))
A1eF4GT;Foo/Bar;Truc/Machin
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure I can make it work. I get "A1eF4GT;Foo/Bar;Foo/Machin;Truc/Bar;Truc/Machin"